# Areas in asp.net mvc 6.0 does not find Index file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I want to use Areas in an MVC 6.0 project.

These are my routes:

```
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                // NOT work
                routes.MapRoute("new_default",
                        "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
              // NOT work
              routes.MapRoute("areaRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}");



                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                // Uncomment the following line to add a route for porting Web API 2 controllers.
                // routes.MapWebApiRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
            });
```

I created on my root project an

```
"Areas" folder
"Application" folder
 with a 
Controllers/HomeController.cs
Views/Home/Index.cshtml

[Area("Application")]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

When I go to the url:

domain/Application/Home it does not find the Index file I get a 404, Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your attribute route's template to like `[Route("[area]/[controller]")]`. Now your requests like `/application/home` should work fine.

Here `area`, `controller` and `action` are route tokens which would be replaced by the area, controller and action names that this attribute is decorated on. This is a new concept in ASP.NET 5 to reduce redundancy in supplying the same values again and again.

Note that when you decorate controllers/actions with attribute routes, they cannot be reached from conventional routes defined in your startup class.

Comment: funny... all blogs that I found about asp.net mvc 6.0 do not mention your hint in their samples, wonder wether they really work... thanks!